# Why does the latest clang not define the feature test macro __cpp_coroutines?

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, compiler-bug, c++-coroutine

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
#if __has_include(<coroutine>)
    std::cout << "__has_include(<coroutine>)" << std::endl;
#endif

#if defined(__cpp_impl_coroutine)
    std::cout << "__cpp_impl_coroutine is defined." << std::endl;
#endif

#if defined(__cpp_coroutines)
    std::cout << "__cpp_coroutines is defined." << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "__cpp_coroutines IS NOT defined!" << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

My compiler is clang-18.1.0.

Build the code with `clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ ./main.cpp`, and the output is:

```
__has_include(<coroutine>)
__cpp_impl_coroutine is defined.
__cpp_coroutines IS NOT defined!
```

**Why does the latest clang not define the feature test macro __cpp_coroutines?**

Comment: Perhaps you need to include the `<coroutine>` header?

Comment: perhaps file a bug?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, no effect even if `#include <coroutine>`.

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fcoroutines

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, no effect even if `clang++ -std=c++20 -fcoroutines -stdlib=libc++ ./main.cpp`, and also, if `-std=c++20` is given, `-fcoroutines` will be ignored.

Comment: `__cpp_coroutines` doesn't seem to be a [feature test macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test). Did you mean `__cpp_lib_coroutine`? https://godbolt.org/z/n666xfhWf

Comment: @AlanBirtles, see this link: https://omegaup.com/docs/cpp/en/cpp/feature_test.html

Comment: That seems to be an archive of cppreference from 2018 https://omegaup.com/docs/cpp/en/ so predates the finalisation of c++20

Comment: I do not see `__cpp_coroutines` in [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test).

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__cpp_coroutines` is an [outdated feature test macro](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4649.pdf), it was split into `__cpp_lib_coroutine` and `__cpp_impl_coroutine` [before c++20 was standardised](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3393). You should use the up to date cpp reference pages for the latest information https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test

Clang seems to have stopped defining `__cpp_coroutines` since version 17 https://godbolt.org/z/nc1GhGGTo

Comment: Also, to make sure the supported feature test macros are there, add `#include <version>`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem where I needed code to compile with:

- LLVM 15 using C++17 - this works
- LLVM 15 using C++20 - this works
- LLVM 17 using C++17 - did not work :-(
- LLVM 17 using C++20 - this works

I used the following

```cpp
#include <version> // Needed to pull in __cpp_lib_coroutine (can gate on compiler version if needed)

// This is just to demonstrate whether these feature tests are present at all
#if defined(__cpp_coroutines)
# pragma message("__cpp_coroutines defined")
#endif

#if defined(__cpp_lib_coroutine)
# pragma message("__cpp_lib_coroutine defined")
#endif

// This determines whether coroutines are present and makes a handy cross-compatible compiler flag for it
#if !defined(__clang__)
# error This file should only be used to compile with clang
#else
#if __clang_major__ < 17
    #if defined(__cpp_coroutines)
        #define COROUTINES_PRESENT 1
        #pragma message("Coroutines present clang < 17!") // Just FYI
    #else
        #define COROUTINES_PRESENT 0
        #pragma message("Coroutines absent clang < 17!")  // Just FYI
    #endif
#else
    #if defined(__cpp_lib_coroutine)
        #define COROUTINES_PRESENT 1
        #pragma message("Coroutines present clang >= 17!")  // Just FYI
    #else
        #define COROUTINES_PRESENT 0
        #pragma message("Coroutines absent clang >= 17!")  // Just FYI
    #endif
#endif
#endif

// This is where your code goes
#if COROUTINES_PRESENT
#pragma message("Coroutines present!")
#else
#pragma message("Coroutines absent!")
#endif

int main(){

}
```

To compile use:

```
clang++15 main.cpp --std=c++17 -fcoroutines-ts
clang++15 main.cpp --std=c++20
clang++17 main.cpp --std=c++20
```

From [this discussion](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/59110) it looks as though `-fcoroutines-ts` was deprecated in LLVM 16 so to use coroutines in LLVM 17 you need c++20.